# IOS5 - How To play videos within a programatically created View?

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es, view

I'm creating a game for iPad using OpenGL. I have created a view (with a simple background) grammatically using the following code:

```
- (void) addNewView {    
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIView *polygonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 60, 0, 900, 900)];
    polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    //here play a movie:-)

    [window addSubview:polygonView];
    [polygonView release];

}
```

and i'm display it using the following code within a case switch in a window:

```
[self addNewView];
```

This all works well.

However, I need help to implement a video feature in this view, when it is displayed.
Can anyone provide me with assistance in the form of code or a link to a relevant tutorial that can aid me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

[MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
and
[MPMoviePlayerViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html)

That should get you started.